# VBA - How to find frequencies of "x" and "y" in a list

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of names on one page of an excel workbook, I need to find how often each of these names appears in that column and display it on another sheet. For example, the code needs to count "CS" however many times it appears in this column and display it on a separate sheet, then the same with "Grad" and so on.  Any tips?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution with a simple function 
=COUNTIF(Individual_Stats!D6:D999,"CS")

Comment: good start but not exactly what you asked for ... this only displays the number of one value, and you have to hard code the value ... Pivot Tables are more flexible and mor dynamic ... plus you can filter on strings in the Pivot table row labels ... just give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

That's the primary use of Pivot tables.

[image]